# AWS RDS SQL Server - distributing queries to read-replicas

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-rds

We are using AWS RDS SQL Server and need some help with solving the following problem - how to handle heavy read queries and prevent the report queries from blocking the rest of the operations.
We were hoping RDS Multi-AZ would solve this problem for us, but it turned out Multi-AZ for SQL Server does not create readable replicas.

Comment: What do you mean "Multi-AZ for SQL Server does not create read-replicas"? And your are using AWS RDS MS SQL right?

Comment: RDS Multi-AZ SQL Server Replicas are not readable. End point is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Database Migration Service doesn't really help with MSSQL on RDS(1).

You can replicate once, but cannot do any continuous replication due to how RDS is locked down.

I have found this product to be looking somewhat useful: [CloudBasic RDS AlwaysOn](http://cloudbasic.net/aws/rds/AlwaysOn/)

(1)http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon Database Migration Service to create a readable replica. https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

As per the FAQ's:

Q. In addition to one-time data migration, can I use AWS Database Migration Service for continuous data replication?

Yes, you can use AWS Database Migration Service for both one-time data migration into RDS and EC2-based databases as well as for continuous data replication. AWS Database Migration Service will capture changes on the source database and apply them in a transactionally-consistent way to the target. Continuous replication can be done from your data center to the databases in AWS or in the reverse, replicating to a database in your datacenter from a database in AWS. Ongoing continuous replication can also be done between homogenous or heterogeneous databases. For ongoing replication it would be preferable to use Multi-AZ for high-availability.